# Visual C++ Error: Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++

Hello i compliled my c++ program and if i start the .exe i got a error
[Image from the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCi8z.png)

This is my source(main.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

// using
using namespace std;

bool fexists(const char *filename);

int main() {
try {
    HANDLE h;
    string cClipboard = "";

    CreateDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\Clipboard Logger", NULL);
    if (!fexists("C:\\Program Files\\Clipboard Logger\\log.txt")) {
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("C:\\Program Files\\Clipboard Logger\\log.txt", "w");
        fclose(fp);
    }

    while (true) {
        if (!OpenClipboard(0)) {
            Sleep(2000);
            continue;
        }

        h = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
        CloseClipboard();

        if ((char *)h == cClipboard) {
            Sleep(2000);
            continue;
        }
        cClipboard = (char *)h;

        time_t t = time(0);
        struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("C:\\Program Files\\Clipboard Logger\\log.txt", "a");
        int day = now->tm_mday;
        int month = now->tm_mon + 1;
        int year = now->tm_year + 1900;
        int sec = now->tm_sec;
        int min = now->tm_min;
        int hour = now->tm_hour;
        char logLine[sizeof((char *)h) + 64];
        sprintf(logLine, "%d.%d.%d %d.%d.%d %s\n", hour, min, sec, day, month, year, (char *)h);
        fprintf(fp, (char *)logLine);
        fclose(fp);

        cout << (char *)logLine << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
} catch (...) {

}
}

bool fexists(const char *filename) {
ifstream ifile(filename);
if (ifile)
    return true;
return false;
}
```

iam new in c++ and i dont know how to fix it, because if i debug the program all works fine but with the exe it doesnt work.

Comment: I suggest you [learn how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) sooner rather than later.

Comment: Tip: Don't use C style casts in C++. Instead avoid casting as much as possible and if you can't avoid it use the C++ casting operators.

Comment: I expect that UAC would not be too happy with you writing files to `C:\Program Files`. You did not check if fp is after this line: `fp = fopen("C:\\Program Files\\Clipboard Logger\\log.txt", "a");`